# How to change textColor of a spinner programmatically

Tags: android, spinner

I am using the following code to setup my spinner :

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.country_code_spinner_item,
            countrySpinnerOptions){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
            return v;
        }
    };
```

This assigns the default color of the text to "#808080"

Now i have also implemented **setOnTouchListener** method for this spinner. What i want is although initially the color text of the spinner is 808080. But after the spinner is touched and a new text is chosen from a list. The color now permanently changes to BLACK.

How do i implement this ?

Thanks

Comment: please add the onTouchListener also,

Comment: you should refer these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312043/how-to-change-spinner-text-color