# Set the text color of an android spinner

Tags: android

I have tried [How to change spinner text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312043/how-to-change-spinner-text-color) to no avail.

I am trying to change the text color in a Spinner element.

Array adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.hour_spinner, hourList);
```

hour_spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Intellisense does not recognize the R.layout.hour_spinner

It is the layout folder. Any idea why the hour_spinner is not found by the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without android:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.hour_spinner, hourList);
```

replace with:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.hour_spinner, hourList);
```

if it doesn't help , give us more codes.

Comment: when you call R.layout.hour_spinner , you call your custom layout. When you call android.R.layout.hour_spinner , it's android's layout.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason for your issue ...

R.layout.* are layouts you provide (in res/layout, for example).

android.R.layout.* are layouts that ship with the Android SDK.'

As Milanz suggested, try without android